# "Cyclic" continuum

Tags: gn.general-topology, cohomology, definitions

On p. 221 of http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v08/tp08113.pdf, I found the following definition:

"A curve is said to be *cyclic* if its first Čech cohomology group with integer coefficients does not vanish".

Here, a curve means a homogeneous metric continuum of dimension 1.

Can someone explain this definition in different, more elementary, terms, and give some examples to illustrate the meaning?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the *first Čech cohomology group with integer coefficients* may seem not *elementary*. Then use the characterization of it as the first Borsuk's cohomotopy group (or it appears as the *Brushlinsky's group* in the well-known text on Homotopy Theory by Hu). This group's elements are simply the homotopy classes of mappings into $\ \mathbb S^1.$ Space $\ S^1\ $ is a topological group, it induces the group structure on the homotopy classes.